# Can I use screws or nail to fasten shower liner?

Tags: bathroom

I've read articles where either one is used to secure shower liner to studs when making a shower bed. Is one better then the other?

Comment: Better in what sense? It's not like they're going to fall out. Use what the manufacturer requires or what you prefer to install.

Comment: I am talking about Oatey shower liner, they mention nails, but then I see videos where screws are used. Does the manufacturer mention nails and not screws because screws can create micro tears in liner? I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used nails, I have used screws. Make sure you keep any fastener well above the curb of the shower. I typically run my liner up over 6" above the preslope and nail or screw only at the top edge using a heat gun, not set to high, to help ease the folding in the corners.

One advantage screws have over nails is they are easy to remove to readjust if needed. The downside is the material really puckers bad around the screw head when you draw the screw in tight. As mentioned in a comment, a washer would help this, but then you have the extra thickness to deal with under the cement board.

Nails work well, but if you have to adjust, and you do not leave the nails a little proud to make it easy to pull and reset.... well there's the issue, it can be a real bear to remove without damaging the edge of the liner to a degree.

Answer (score 1):

It's just gotta stay there until you tile it. It's supposed to wrap up the wall ~2" so w/e you penetrate it with: the hole doesn't matter.

With screws you need washers or it will probably over-sink and tear. With (roofing) nails it should be fine. That is, if you even have any 'hand bangers'.

Comment: They mention nails because you can use the same ones you mounted the tub with; those are the only guys who carry around galvanized roofing hand bangers. Everybody else uses screws or collated nails for everything.